# Cast to ArrayList

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

I've stored an ArrayList in a Map and I'm trying to get this ArrayList back:

```
//init map with data: Map<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>>
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  Entry entry = iterator.next();
  ArrayList value = (ArrayList)entry.getValue();
}
```

The cast of the entry.getValue() to a general ArrayList seems to work, however when I try to cast it to the specific ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> value = (ArrayList<MyObject>)entry.getValue();
```

the compiler throughs an error. Some sort of "Warning from last compilation".
Is it possible to cast it to my specific ArrayList so that I can loop through it with a For-Each-Loop afterwards?

Comment: How do you mean that? I want to iterate through the Map and want to get the specific ArrayList<MyObject> in each loop.

Comment: I though you were accessing the value of the map manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are creating Map like this

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>>();
```

you don't need to cast, and hence there is no **WARNING**.

```
for(Entry<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = e.getKey();
    ArrayList<MyObject> value = e.getValue();
}
```

Introduction to Generics was done, to basically avoid these kinds of warnings. With generics we should define the "type" of objects we would like to store in the data-structure. Hence while retrieving, the Java compiler knows exactly what object the data-structure is returning.

Comment: It's a LinkedHashMap and I get incompatible types when not casting.

Comment: @freakout you should [program oriented to interfaces, not to implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197). By doing that, you won't have any casting problem.

Comment: It is working! The problem seems to be my while loop to iterate through the data. Your for loop works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Yeah I know, Eran, but the way sanbhat presents here is much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But looping with an iterator is the only possible option in some cases (such as the case when you want to be able to remove items from the collections while iterating).

Comment: @Eran I never said that using iterator is wrong. Back to OP's problem, this is not the case :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well, if we're back to OP's problem - OP used an explicit iterator in the question, which is why I used one in my answer :)

Comment: @Eran that doesn't stop us to show OP other ways to solve the problem :).

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<MyObject> value = e.getValue();
```

should be ok, no need to cast because you have defined the right type:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>>
```